# Openning http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/no_tidy_lib.html instead of Homepage in Firefox

Tags: firefox, homepage

Whenever I open firefox , it tries to open `http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/no_tidy_lib.html`.
The above website isn't my home page , Google is my home page.

How can I fox it ?

Comment: +1 for the (I'm assuming) pun. I hope you end up foxing it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went to that page.. I think you're being sent there as a means of reporting "FATAL ERROR : The dynamic C library  contained in the extension file could not be found."

The [page you linked](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/no_tidy_lib.html) provides a series of solutions, depending on your particular situation. For example, the first such solution is to reinstall the dynamic C library.

I suggest you go read that page in detail and follow the instructions there. I suspect once you've done that, starting up Firefox will take you to your home page normally.

**EDIT: Here are the instructions from that page, as per request:**

---

**Cause 0 : since 16-NOV-2007, there is a bug in addon.mozilla.org for MacOsX !**

Addons.mozilla.org proposes a update for the extension for MacOSX since the 16-NOV-2007 while there is no such update on the site. A bug was logged in bugzilla. [Please vote for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404160) if you want it to be solved !

**Solution:**

- reinstall the version for your platform.

  - [0.841 for MacOsX intel](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/download.html)
  - [0.795 for MacOs X PPC](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/download_070.html)
    (Notice, I am looking for somebody to compile the version 0.841 on PPC !!)

---

**Cause 1:  Operating system mismatch**

This can happen when you have installed a version that is not for your Operating system (OS). For example, installing the Linux version on Windows or the opposite. The extension is available on Windows, MacOsX, Linux 32bits, Linux 64bits and Linux PPC. This happens mostly due to bad autodetection of the OS or caching issue in addons.mozilla.org.

**Solution:** re-install the extension for your OS.

1. Please, look at the list of OS here, http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/download.html and install the version for your OS. Take care to allow this site to install an extension (green toolbar at the top)
2. Retry in addons.mozilla.org and take care that the version installed is the one for your OS.

---

**Cause 2: Linux**

A. On linux, depending of your linux distribution, it can be that the standard C++ libraries installed on your distribution are not the one linked with the extension. To correct this, please read the detailed info, here:

http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/faq.html#LINUX

Take also care that the extension is different for Linux 32bits (most common), Linux 64bits and Linux PPC.

B. In an update on Debian from about June/July 2006, solved in about August 2006. The extension does not work on Debian anymore. The reason is the way debian has changed his way to link the XPCOM library in Firefox.

---

**Cause 3: Windows Vista**

You need to be administrator to install the extension on Firefox in Windows Vista.

---

**Cause 4: Seamonkey upgrade**

When reinstalling a new version of Seamonkey on an existing one, Seamonkey warns that it will deregister all components. Practically, the library of the extension is deinstalled. To solve this, just reinstall the extension.  [Download here](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/download.html)

---

**Cause 5: Browser (Netscape 7.x, 8,x, Seamonkey 1.0.x)**

Like told in the download area, the extension has been  tested on Firefox, Mozilla Suite 1.7.
It is reported to work on Flock without any issue.

It does not work on Seamonkey, nor on Netscape 7.x or 8.x.
If you use these browser please deinstall the extension. See uninstall instructions below.

---

**Case 6: Other**

[Check the forums](http://www.htmlpedia.org/phpBB/)

If you do not find an answer, add your question in it .
Then contact me if you do not find a solution : Marc Gueury : mgueury@skynet.be

---

**To uninstall the extension:**

In Firefox, Flock,
- go in the Tools/Add-ons menu (called Extensions in previous versions)
- choose HTML validator in the Extension list
- click uninstall
- restart Firefox.

For other browsers, see
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_extensions
- http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/faq.html#UNINSTALL

---

**Additional info:**

Symptoms:

In the Java console, you will see this error message

```
Error: Components.classes['@mozilla.org/tidy;1'] has no properties
Source File: chrome://tidy/content/tidyUtil.js
Line: 96
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post with the Instruction there, I cannot open the page !!!

Comment: Yup, took a few minutes, so there ya go. Hope that helps you?